# mlcp does not load large number of files in directory

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

SEE EDIT BELOW

we use MarkLogic Content Pump to load data into a ML8 database.
We have a dev environment in which all is ok and a prod in which mlcp will not get passed the assesment of the number of files to process.

We have 2.1 million JSON docs we want to load.

On the dev server (ML8 + CentOS6) we see this:

```
15/07/13 13:19:35 INFO contentpump.ContentPump: Hadoop library version: 2.0.0-alpha
15/07/13 13:19:35 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type is set to MIXED.  The format of the  inserted documents will be determined by the MIME  type specification configured on MarkLogic Server.
15/07/13 13:19:35 WARN util.KerberosName: Kerberos krb5 configuration not found, setting default realm to empty
15/07/13 13:23:06 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2147329
15/07/13 13:24:08 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 0%
15/07/13 13:34:43 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 1%
15/07/13 13:43:42 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 2%
15/07/13 13:51:15 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 3%
```

And finishes ok, data load ok.

Now we use the same data on a different machine the prod server (ML8 + CentOS**7**) we get

```
15/07/14 17:02:21 INFO contentpump.ContentPump: Hadoop library version: 2.6.0
15/07/14 17:02:21 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type is set to MIXED.  The format of the  inserted documents will be determined by the MIME  type specification configured on MarkLogic Server.
```

Besides the different OS we also have a more recent version of mlcp on de prod server 2.6.0 instead of 2.0.0. If we use the same command for importing a directory with only 2000 files it works on prod ...

The job gets stuck when counting the number of files to process...

What can be the issue?

START EDIT
we put mlcp in DEBUG and tested with a small samle.zip

result:

```
[ashraf@77-72-150-125 ~]$ mlcp.sh import -host localhost -port 8140 -username ashraf -password duurz44m -input_file_path /home/ashraf/sample2.zip -input_compressed true  -mode local -output_uri_replace  "\".*,''\"" -output_uri_prefix incoming/linkedin/ -output_collections incoming,incoming/linkedin -output_permissions slush-dikw-node-role,read
15/07/16 16:36:31 DEBUG contentpump.ContentPump: Command: IMPORT
15/07/16 16:36:31 DEBUG contentpump.ContentPump: Arguments: -host localhost -port 8140 -username ashraf -password duurz44m -input_file_path /home/ashraf/sample2.zip -input_compressed true -mode local -output_uri_replace ".*,''" -output_uri_prefix incoming/linkedin/ -output_collections incoming,incoming/linkedin -output_permissions slush-dikw-node-role,read 
15/07/16 16:36:31 INFO contentpump.ContentPump: Hadoop library version: 2.6.0
15/07/16 16:36:31 DEBUG contentpump.ContentPump: Running in: localmode
15/07/16 16:36:31 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type is set to MIXED.  The format of the  inserted documents will be determined by the MIME  type specification configured on MarkLogic Server.
15/07/16 16:36:32 DEBUG contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Thread pool size: 4
15/07/16 16:36:32 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/07/16 16:36:33 DEBUG contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Thread Count for Split#0 : 4
15/07/16 16:36:33 DEBUG contentpump.CompressedDocumentReader: Starting file:/home/ashraf/sample2.zip
15/07/16 16:36:33 DEBUG contentpump.MultithreadedMapper: Running with 4 threads
15/07/16 16:36:33 DEBUG mapreduce.ContentWriter: Connect to localhost
15/07/16 16:36:33 DEBUG mapreduce.ContentWriter: Connect to localhost
15/07/16 16:36:33 DEBUG mapreduce.ContentWriter: Connect to localhost
15/07/16 16:36:33 DEBUG mapreduce.ContentWriter: Connect to localhost
15/07/16 16:36:34 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 0%
15/07/16 16:36:39 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 100%
2015-07-16 16:39:11.483 WARNING [19] (AbstractRequestController.runRequest): Error parsing HTTP headers: Premature EOF, partial header line read: ''
15/07/16 16:39:12 DEBUG contentpump.CompressedDocumentReader: Closing file:/home/ashraf/sample2.zip
15/07/16 16:39:12 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPumpStats: 
15/07/16 16:39:12 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: ATTEMPTED_INPUT_RECORD_COUNT: 1993
15/07/16 16:39:12 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: SKIPPED_INPUT_RECORD_COUNT: 0
15/07/16 16:39:12 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Total execution time: 160 sec
```

Only the first json file is in the database, the rest is dropped/lost?

Is tehre an issue with newline in JSON files?

```
(AbstractRequestController.runRequest): Error parsing HTTP headers: Premature EOF, partial header line read: ''
```

any hints would be great.

hugo

Comment: MLCP has a conf/log4j.properties file. Please enable debugging (uncomment the two lines at the end) and let us know what that tells us.

Comment: we put mlcp in DEBUG mode... see edited question for result

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell what is happening. I think support would be interested in this case. Can you send them or me a mail with more details (and the files perhaps).

As a workaround: it shouldn't be difficult to use the same **MLCP** version on prod server as you used on dev, just put it next to the other one (or anywhere you like), and make sure you reference that one (hint: in Roxy you have the `mlcp-home` setting).

You could also consider zipping the json documents and use the `-input_compressed` option.

HTH!